# What is the Differences Between Model and ModelMap in Spring

Tags: java, spring, model

I am using ModelAndView in the Spring and Spring Boot projects to pass the parameters and set the view from the controller.
I have discovered that I can also do that by using Model and ModelMap.
ModelAndView is different from these because it returns the parameters and the view object in a single return value. However I could not find much difference between these two.

I know that Model is interface but ModelMap is a class. Additionally Model is newer and it can be used to merge attributes by taking a map as input.

Is there any other difference or advantage of one on the other?

Thanks.